# iOS FB SDK Access Token is nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm using FBSDKCoreKit and FBSDKLoginKit v13.1

I have a FB Login Button in my application with the following handler:

```
- (void)  loginButton:(FBSDKLoginButton *)loginButton
didCompleteWithResult:(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *)result
                error:(NSError *)error{
    if (error || (result && result.isCancelled)) {
      return;
    }
    [self loginWithFB];
}
```

This part of the code works fine, the buttons state also changes to `Log out` after a successful login, however when I want to make graph requests they fail because it doesn't have a FB Access token (`[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken] is nil`)

```
- (void) loginWithFB {
    NSString *fbAccessToken = [[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken] tokenString];

    [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
      initWithGraphPath:@"me"
      parameters:@{@"fields": @"id"}
      tokenString:fbAccessToken
      version:nil
      HTTPMethod:@"GET"
     ]
     startWithCompletion:^(id<FBSDKGraphRequestConnecting> connection, id result, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            ...
        } else {
            ...
        }
     }];
}
```

I am not sure what is causing this, the bootstrap (AppDelegate, plist, etc.) setup for the FB SDK is set up correctly (checked this more than I would like), but the [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/class/FBSDKLoginManager/) clearly state that when the button has a logged in state, the currentAccessToken should be available.
(`FBSDKLoginManager works directly with [FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken] and sets the "currentAccessToken" upon successful authorizations (or sets nil in case of logOut).`)

Comment: In `result`, there should be a property `token`, could you check it? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/class/FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult/

Comment: @Larme the token in `result` is nil too (`_token = (FBSDKAccessToken *) nil 0x0000000000000000`)